# Azure, includeInlineCount();

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-sql-database

Can somebody tell me how I can use includeInlineCount(); in android studio to count the number of rows in an azure database table?

I have tried this method:

```
final MobileServiceList<Crime> result = mToDoTable.where().includeInlineCount().execute().get();
```

And this method:

```
final MobileServiceList<Crime> result = mToDoTable.includeInlineCount().execute().get();
```

I did not get an error from running this code. Instead the textView that was suppose to display the number of rows just displayed the vaule of the first column for each row. How can I count these values and display that number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count number of strings returned from Azure query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872031/count-number-of-strings-returned-from-azure-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Cain，it seem to be a duplicate thread with [Count number of strings returned from Azure query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872031/count-number-of-strings-returned-from-azure-query), please see that answer.

Best Regards.